# What do I set my columns as in Connect Four (made with tkinter/Python)?

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

I'm working on my final project for my intro to CS class, and decided to create Connect Four using tkinter from Python. I drew my board using tkinter's 'create_rectangle()' but now I'm stuck on how to label/call/refer my columns. My grid is 700x600 pixels, with 7 columns, and 6 rows. In order to keep track of the pieces during the game, I need to see where they are, so that I can make a boolean statement of whether player 1 or player 2 won. So would I use the coordinates or rename it as:

```
self.main_window.geometry("700x640") 

self.top_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
self.top_frame.pack(side='top')

self.bottom_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
self.bottom_frame.pack(side='bottom') 
# Creating the board
self.board = tkinter.Canvas(self.main_window, width = 700, height=600)
self.board.pack(anchor='nw')
# A rectangle is made (top left coord., bottom right coord.)
# Fill color = #Hexnumber 
self.board.create_rectangle(0, 0, 700, 600, fill="#1E90FF")
# Line is drawn after rectangle cause it is drawn ONTOP (order matters) 
self.board.create_line(0, 0, 0, 700)
self.board.create_line(0, 0, 600, 0)
# Drawn in rows
for rows in range(100, 600, 100): 
    self.board.create_line(0, rows, 700, rows, fill="")
# Drawn in columns
for columns in range(100, 700, 100):
    self.board.create_line(columns, 0, columns, 600, fill="")
# Drawn in circles
for i in range(0, 700, 100):
    for k in range(0, 700, 100):
        self.board.create_oval(i, k, i+100, k+100, fill="")

# Set up for circle pieces 
self.yellow_piece = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="piece1round.gif")
self.black_piece = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="piece2round.gif")
self.empty_piece = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="empty.gif")

# Created a button & placing them at the bottom left of the window frame
self.buttonOne = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame, width=13, text="Column 1", command = "?")
self.buttonOne.pack(side = 'left')
self.buttonTwo = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame, width=13, text="Column2")
self.buttonTwo.pack(side='left')
self.buttonThree = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame, width=13, text="Column3")
self.buttonThree.pack(side='left')
self.buttonFour = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame, width=13, text="Column4")
self.buttonFour.pack(side='left')
self.buttonFive = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame, width=13, text="Column5")
self.buttonFive.pack(side='left')
self.buttonSix = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame, width=13, text="Column6")
self.buttonSix.pack(side='left')
self.buttonSeven = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame, width=13, text="Column7")
self.buttonSeven.pack(side='left')

# Set up values for columns and rows
self.board_width = 700
self.board_row = 600

self.column1 = "?"
```

[ConnectFourBoardDisplay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnVlV.jpg)

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: What I didn't include was my startscreen, but it had my import tkinter, and such. I hope this is more organized; and a photo of the grid I made is attached

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest is something along the lines of

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
c = tk.Canvas(root, width = 700, height = 600)
c.pack()

board_state = []
for i in range(0, 700, 100):
    column = []
    for k in range(0, 700, 100):
        column.append(c.create_oval(i, k, i+100, k+100, fill=""))
    board_state.append(column)

tk.Button(root, text = "Click", command = change).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

When you create an item on the canvas it returns an integer which is that item's ID. So what we can do is create a list which stores all the ovals you create so that you can reference them.

```
def change():
    c.itemconfig(board_state[0][0], fill = "yellow")

    coords = c.coords(board_state[0][0])
    x, y = (coords[0] + coords[2])/2, (coords[1] + coords[3])/2
    c.delete(board_state[0][0])
    c.create_image( x, y, image = yellow_piece )
```

Now in this function you have two options, first is to configure the fill colour of the item to be what you want depending on which player. Or if you would prefer to use the image instead then you can get the coords of the oval, find the center position, delete the oval and create an image in its place which again would depend on which player.

Now in the example code it just uses the top left corner. You will have to alter it to make it dynamic.

Now I would assume in the rest of your code you have a model to go with your view ( MVC ) in which case you could go with the alternate method of using `c.delete(tk.ALL)` which clears the canvas and then have another function the redraws everything with an if statement to determine if this spot on the canvas is empty of has a player piece.